# What is the problem in the given CSS code? It is not working on iPhone

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iphone, frontend

This loader is working on laptop and android but it is not working on iPhone(Safari and Chrome) and Mac(Safari).
Checked all the properties using dev tools on safari using browserstack testing.
Couldn't solve the issue using previous answers. I am think it is a z index fault, but didn't find any issue pertaining to that too.

Correct - [On Windows and Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2uz9.png)

Incorrect - [On iPhone and Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcLU9.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="planet">
                    <div class="ring"></div>
                    <div class="cover-ring"></div>
                    <div class="spots">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>loading</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
        .loader {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #001534 !important;
        }

        .loader > .content {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet {
            width: 65%;
            height: 65%;
            background-color: #c05227;
            border-radius: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            transform-origin: center center;
            box-shadow: inset 2px -10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            animation: planet 5s ease infinite alternate;
            /* planet ring */
            /* to cover the back of the ring */
            /* planet spots */
        }

        @keyframes planet {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(10deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(-10deg);
            }
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .ring {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: #bacbd9;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            transform-origin: 33% center;
            box-shadow: 2px -10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -5px -10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            animation: ring 3s ease infinite;
            /* small ball */
            /* inner ring */
        }

        @keyframes ring {
            0% {
                transform: rotateX(110deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate(-50px, 5px);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotateX(110deg) rotateZ(360deg) translate(-50px, 5px);
            }
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .ring:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 10px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: #7ea1bf;
            z-index: 2;
            left: calc(0px - 5px);
            box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .ring:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 240px;
            height: 240px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: #7ea1bf;
            box-shadow: inset 2px -10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .cover-ring {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 80%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 80%;
            border-top-left-radius: 100px;
            border-top-right-radius: 100px;
            transform: translate(0px, -17px);
            background-color: #c05227;
            z-index: 2;
            box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #001534;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100%;
            box-shadow: inset -2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            animation: dots 5s ease infinite alternate;
        }

        @keyframes dots {
            0% {
                box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            }

            100% {
                box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            }
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(1) {
            top: 20px;
            right: 50px;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(2) {
            top: 40px;
            left: 50px;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(3) {
            top: 80px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(4) {
            top: 80px;
            left: 90px;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(5) {
            top: 160px;
            left: 70px;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(6) {
            top: 165px;
            left: 125px;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
        }

        .loader > .content .planet .spots span:nth-child(7) {
            top: 90px;
            left: 150px;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
        }

        .loader > .content p {
            color: #bacbd9;
            font-size: 12px;
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -20px;
            font-family: "Mulish", monospace;
            animation: text 4s ease infinite;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        @keyframes text {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(-30px);
                letter-spacing: 0px;
                color: #bacbd9;
            }

            25% {
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                color: #7ea1bf;
            }

            50% {
                transform: translateX(30px);
                letter-spacing: 0px;
                color: #bacbd9;
            }

            75% {
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                color: #7ea1bf;
            }

            100% {
                transform: translateX(-30px);
                letter-spacing: 0px;
                color: #bacbd9;
            }
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: What is "not working?"

Comment: I have added screenshots, it will help in understanding the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Safari does not properly understand `z-index` when using transforms with rotate or translate on the Z axis.

If we adjust the translateZ on the `.cover-ring` selector, that should push up it to sit above the rings:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, -17px, 200px);
```

This means the spots wrapper will also need to be pushed up in the Z axis.

```
transform: translateZ(200px);
```

Reference: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490946/13172018)

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain the issue a little further. Are any of your styles loading or is the css not loading at all? Thanks.

Also style tag should be in the head tag.

Comment: I have added screenshots, it will help in understanding the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than a question.